# Checkbox in NSTextList

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nstextview

How do I get checkbox as a marker in an NSTextList? I want the user to be able to click the checkbox on which it will change to another symbol (a check marker or a thumbs up or the checkbox with a cross inside...). How can I do that? I played a little with NSTextViews and I can get NSTextLists to work. But I have no idea on how to customize it. I am using Xcode 9, swift 4, and try to get it to work for macOS.

Comment: Please add a `osx` flag in your question.